# Chrome Extension Pagestatematcher rules not working

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I have an extension that I've wrote and has been in use for quite a while now with no issues.  I have a pagestatematcher with a css rule to show page action and recently it's stopped working for users.  I have found that I can uninstall the extension and reinstall and most of the time this fixes the issue.  What would cause this to happen?

```
chrome.declarativeContent.onPageChanged.removeRules(undefined, function() {
      chrome.declarativeContent.onPageChanged.addRules([{
        conditions: [
            new chrome.declarativeContent.PageStateMatcher({
                  
                  css: ["table[id='myclass']"]
            })
        ],
            actions: [new chrome.declarativeContent.ShowPageAction()]
      }]);
    });
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing that can remove the rules if you don't call `removeRules` yourself so it must have been a bug in Chrome or the user's profile directory got corrupted.

You can add an `id` to the rule and check if the rule is present each time the extension is loaded for the first time in this user's profile. If there's no rule, re-add it.

```js
chrome.runtime.onStartup.addListener(() => {
  chrome.declarativeContent.onPageChanged.getRules(['foo'], rules => {
    if (!rules[0]) addRules();
  });
});

chrome.runtime.onInstalled.addListener(() => {
  chrome.declarativeContent.onPageChanged.removeRules(addRules);
});

function addRules() {
  chrome.declarativeContent.onPageChanged.addRules([{
    id: 'foo',
    conditions: [
      new chrome.declarativeContent.PageStateMatcher({
        css: ['table[id=\'myclass\']'],
      }),
    ],
    actions: [new chrome.declarativeContent.ShowPageAction()],
  }]);
}
```